# Unable to connect to hotspot from Android device

Tags: wifi, raspbian-jessie

Following  [this tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md) on setting up wi-fi, 
I got the following errors, 
(I added ssid and psk in the file `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`)

```
$sudo ifdown wlan0
ifdown: interface wlan0 not configured

$sudo ifup wlan0
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1 
Failed to bring up wlan0

$sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0 Interface doesn't support scanning

$ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: error fetching interface information:
Device not found
```

I'm currently using raspbian jessie on RPi model B+,
Please help out

Update 1:

```
$sudo ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
   link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT froup default qlen 1000
   link/ether b8:27:eb:53:85:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Much better than your last question ;)  It looks like whatever wifi adapter you are using may not be supported by the operating system.  Paste in the output from `sudo ip link`, then, if you can connect via ethernet, install usbutils (`apt install usbutils`) and paste in the output from `lsusb`.

Comment: It does look like the adapter is not supported since there is no interface for it.  The easiest way to say for sure is to get the USB ID of the chipset used, which `lsusb` would provide.  A USB ID is a pair of 4 digit hexadecimal numbers sometimes expressed like this: `0bc2:1f22`.  There are probably other ways to find it if you have another computer you can plug it into.  If not add the make and model...

Comment: ...I also take it you now have an unregistered account you can't log into :/ If you can still log into your old one, I've created [a chat room for this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42132/green-banana).